# Eslint adds unnecessary space between braces, Prettier shows error

Tags: javascript, eslint, prettier

I'm using prettier and eslint with typescript.

When I write some code and have to leave an empty function for *reasons*, Eslint and Prettier struggle adding and removing spaces between the empty function's braces.

Prettier is removing the space while Eslint is adding it.

What is expected:

```js
  constructor(
    @inject('UsersRepository')
    private usersRepository: IUsersRepository,
  ) {}

const example = ({ variable }) => {
    console.log(variable)
};
```

What I get after saving (Eslint fixing on save):

```js
  constructor(
    @inject('UsersRepository')
    private usersRepository: IUsersRepository,
  ) { }

const example = ({ variable }) => {
    console.log(variable)
};
```

Se the space between the constructor braces? That gives me a `` Delete `·` eslint(prettier/prettier) `` error.

When I save the file, or Prettier removes the space... then Eslint adds it again.

How can I solve this?

EDIT: I want to keep the destructuring assignment space (eg `({ variable })`) but not on empty braces (eg `{}`)

Below, my `.eslintrc.json` and `prettier.config.js`

```js
{
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "node": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "airbnb-base",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "class-methods-use-this": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/camelcase": "off",
    "no-useless-constructor": "off",
    "object-curly-spacing": [
      "error",
      "always"
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
      "error",
      {
        "argsIgnorePattern": "_"
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix": [
      "error",
      {
        "prefixWithI": "always"
      }
    ],
    "import/extensions": [
      "error",
      "ignorePackages",
      {
        "ts": "never"
      }
    ]
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "typescript": {}
    }
  }
}
```

```js
module.exports = {
  singleQuote: true,
  trailingComma: 'all',
  arrowParens: 'avoid',
};
```

Comment: would it be [this prettier setting](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#bracket-spacing)

Comment: Tried and it didn't work. Prettier isn't the issue, as it deletes the space and eslint adds it after. If I use this rule on true, it keeps as it is. If I use this on false, it removes the space from destructuring and empty brackets... but eslint adds the spaces again.

Comment: sorry, so you want the space or don't want it?

Comment: I want it except on empty braces. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: No, you are clear ... it's just that I'm slow :p

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I've had very similar error, but in my case default VSCode TypeScript formatter was messing with braces.
In .vscode/settings.json add:

```
"javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingEmptyBraces": false,
"typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingEmptyBraces": false,
```

You might also find useful option:

```
"[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
}
```

Comment: I never had this problem again but will choose your answer as the right one, as it seems like it would solve the issue.

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: The second block did the work for me, I had the typescript formatter that was conflicting

Answer (score 25):

You should use this in the settings file of vscode.

```
 "prettier.bracketSpacing": false
```

Comment: Or `"bracketSpacing": false` in your .prettierrc file

Answer (score 8):

I had the exact same problem, where prettier stopped working all of a sudden. Auto-format on save(vs code settings) adds a space for braces and linters threw an error on the same. Spend a lot of time debugging this and did the below steps to fix my issue

1: Re-install vscode prettier extension.

Go to vscode => cmd + p and type `ext install esbenp.prettier-vscode`.

2: My vscode settings.json and prettier.js looks somewhat like this

**vscode settings.json**

```
{
   "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
   "source.organizeImports": true,
   "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
   "source.fixAll.tslint": true,
   "source.fixAll.stylelint": true
  },
  "css.validate": false,
  "files.autoSave": "off",
  "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": false,
  "[typescriptreact]": {
   "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
   "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
 "[typescript]": {
   "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
   "editor.formatOnSave": true
  }
 }
```

**Prettier.js**

```
 module.exports = {
  semi: true,
  trailingComma: 'none',
  singleQuote: true,
  printWidth: 80,
  tabWidth: 2,
  endOfLine: 'auto',
  bracketSpacing: true,
  proseWrap: 'always'
};
```

Comment: My auto-formatting randomly broke. After trying different eslint rules out and playing with my .prettierrc file nothing worked. Uninstalling and reinstalling the prettier plugin worked! Thanks!

Comment: @Vinu Prasad commented my bloated settings.json and used your minimal settings. worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

Folks you can try this out. this had worked out for me ✅

Add the below config inside the `.prettierrc.json` file

```json
{
  "bracketSpacing": false  // Default is true 
}
```

Replace `.eslintrc.json` configuration from this

```json
{
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "prettier"],
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error"
  }
}
```

To this

```json
{
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:prettier/recommended"]
}
```

This is the recommended configuration by `eslint-plugin-prettier`: https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier#recommended-configuration

P.S: I thought both do the same job, but after adding a later config, it resolves the issue. I hope it worked out for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I has a bad experience with prettier thanks to this post I managed to put together a nice settings config so Im sharing it here and hopefully it will ;help someone top.

```
"gatsbyhub.commands.build.enableTracing": true,
  "gatsbyhub.commands.build.graphqlTracing": true,
  "gatsbyhub.commands.develop.changeHost": "localhost",
  "window.zoomLevel": 0.6,
  "js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": true,
  "js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true,
  "color-highlight.languages": [
    "*",
  ],
  "importCost.javascriptExtensions": [
    "\\.jsx?$",
  ],
  "html-css-class-completion.JavaScriptLanguages": [
    "javascript",
    "typescriptreact"
  ],
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.renderWhitespace": "none",
  "editor.gotoLocation.multipleTypeDefinitions": "goto",
  "workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromCodeNavigation": true,
  "workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen": true,
  "debug.allowBreakpointsEverywhere": true,
  "debug.toolBarLocation": "docked",
  "blade.format.enable": true,
  "color-highlight.matchWords": true,
  "path-intellisense.showHiddenFiles": true,
  "path-intellisense.mappings": {
    "${workspaceFolder}": true,
    "${workspaceFolder}/gatsby": true,
  },
  "editor.formatOnSave": false,
  "editor.formatOnType": true,
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {},
  "material-icon-theme.activeIconPack": "react_redux",
  "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false,
  "editor.highlightActiveIndentGuide": false,
  "workbench.activityBar.visible": false,
  "javascript.format.enable": true,
  "javascript.autoClosingTags": true,
  "javascript.validate.enable": false,
  "javascript.format.semicolons": "insert",
  "javascript.suggest.jsdoc.generateReturns": true,
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": true,
  "javascript.preferences.quoteStyle": "double",
  "javascript.preferences.useAliasesForRenames": true,
  "javascript.suggest.autoImports": true,
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterConstructor": true,
  "[javascriptreact]": {
    "editor.autoIndent": "advanced",
    "editor.autoClosingQuotes": "beforeWhitespace",
    "breadcrumbs.showVariables": true,
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": true,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.useTabStops": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": false,
    "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file"
  },
  "javascript.suggest.includeCompletionsForImportStatements": true,
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceBeforeAndAfterBinaryOperators": true,
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterSemicolonInForStatements": true,
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterKeywordsInControlFlowStatements": true,
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBrackets": true,
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingJsxExpressionBraces": true,
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingTemplateStringBraces": true,
  "typescript.validate.enable": true,
  "typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "non-relative",
  "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBrackets": true,
```

I haven't started coding in typescript yet but when I do lll male a new config :)

Happy coding